# Regex for matching anything after particular directory

Tags: regex, wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

I have a page set up on my wordpress install called /forum.

I want anything that comes after forum e.g. /forum/login.asp?helloworld=hi  etc to be put as a query string to forum so it goes to the forum page and I can obtain this 'login.asp?helloworld=hi' as a variable.

I've created a rule on my IIS server which is above the default wordpress rule.

I used this regex:

/forum/(.*)$

to rewrite to this /forum/?test={R:1}

and made it so it stops processing any other rules if we get a match.

All I seem to get is the Wordpress 404 page. Im absolutely useless at redirects/rewrites/regex etc so any help would be awesome!

Comment: I tested it and mine on the IIS rewrite page for the site and they both produce matches, yet when i'm on the site they just go to the 404 page. Is there something wordpress is doing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What language are you doing this in? PHP, Perl, Java, ?

Comment: The site is in php (wordpress) (ignore the asp bit above, it's related to the project, the sites not asp).

I'm doing the rewrites on the server (windows server) GUI.

Comment: Post your wordpress rule code so we can furthur help you

Comment: Wordpress just matches * and rewrites to index.php unless it's a file or folder. Thanks for your help!!